# Nacos connectivity issue

Tags: connection, connection-pooling, connectivity, nacos, alibaba

Caused by: com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:9847
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

I have updated spring boot to 2.7.1 and nacos version to 0.2.12. But it is adding offset 1000 and i am not able to connect to nacos server. Please help.